# Proportions test using values in columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, testing

So I'm stuck with something that would appear to be basic, but anyway. I've got the dataframe (Dat.f) below, and I need to run a proportions.test (Chi.squared) on Posgain.vector and Neggain.vector and extract the P value
using the formula prop.test.

if manually done using the first row as an example this will turn out to be

```
 P<-prop.test(x=c(4,4), n=c(16,10)[2]

  Posgain.vector Freq Neggain.vector Freq.1 PosRef NegRef
1           A1BG    4           A1BG      4     16     10
2       A1BG-AS1    4       A1BG-AS1      4     16     10
3           A1CF    4           A1CF      1     16     10
4            A2M    1            A2M      1     16     10
5        A2M-AS1    1        A2M-AS1      1     16     10
6          A2ML1    1          A2ML1      1     16     10
```

The trouble is I can't quite figure out how to apply this function to each row so it pastes in the second and fourth columns on that row into x and applies the formula with n staying the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very similar approach to @agstudy, but extracting the p.value:

```
df = data.frame(Posgain.vector=c("A1BG", "A1BG-AS1", "A1CF", "A2M", "A2M-AS1", "A2ML1"),
                Freq = c(4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1),
                Neggain.vector=c("A1BG", "A1BG-AS1", "A1CF", "A2M", "A2M-AS1", "A2ML1"),
                Freq.1 = c(4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                PosRef = rep(16, 6),
                NegRef = rep(10, 6))
apply(df[, c(2,4)], 1, function(row) prop.test(x=c(row[1], row[2]), n=c(16, 10))$p.value)

# [1] 0.7117401 0.7117401 0.6652053 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
```